# JSON Schema nested allOf/anyOf/oneOf not working

Tags: json, validation, intellij-idea, schema, jsonschema

I try to validate this JSON with the following schema.

```
{
  "a": "1"
}
```

Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "a": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "b": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(This is just a simplified example to demonstrate the problem.)

The validation is supposed to fail ("a" must be integer not string) but the error is not detected.
But if I replace allOf with oneOf or anyOf, it fails as expected.
Also if I replace oneOf by anyOf in the nested schema.
Am I missing something, or the validator is buggy?

EDIT - It appears to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA validator. It works in  python3-jsonschema, Java Everit, jsonschema.dev.

Comment: This example doesn't actually show a reproducible problem. It works as expected... look: https://jsonschema.dev/s/RilXu

Comment: I suspect I know the problem, but I cannot confirm, because I cannot reproduce with THIS exaple. I have no doubt you're facing a challenge =]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the IntelliJ IDEA issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284601